# The So and Such Choice

Tags: adverbs

We can say:

> I know such a good place

I heard we could also say:

> I know a so good place

OR

> I know so good a place

Is it true or not and how would it be if not and if yes and so on=)

Comment: To me, your first alternative is completely unacceptable on syntactic grounds, whereas the second is just somewhat "awkward". For an example of that general construction (***so + adjective*** before ***indefinite article + noun***) that's not so awkward, consider something like *He's not **so honest a man** as you think.* Most people would probably say ***not such an honest man*** there, but there's nothing really wrong with the first version. Whereas *He's not **a so honest man** as you think* is just a complete no-no.

Comment: I know ***such a good place*** and you are not even listening to my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie: And *I know **a place so good** you wouldn't believe it*. Or at a pinch, *It was **so good a place** we decided to go there again next year*. But it's not really on to introduce a ***so**-based*  element in between the article and the noun parts of ***a place***.

Comment: I was only talking about  your naysaying the first one. It is actually said. It was ***such a good idea*** and you panned it.

Comment: @Lambie - but would you say "I know such a good idea"? Really?  I just can't imagine any context where this would be OK, at least not in British English.  Sounds foreign to me.  "I have such a good idea" might be OK in some contexts.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have such a good idea and you are not interested. have such a good idea and know such a good place

Comment: @Lambie - but would you say "I know such a good idea"?

Comment: @BillyKerr I already answered you with examples. Why are you repeating this??

Comment: @Lambie - yeah I saw that, but I find your example quite strange as well, that's why I'm asking. It's interesting.  It may be something that more acceptable in your variety of English than mine (UK/Scottish English). I've been trying to google ngram it, but most examples seem to be split between sentences ". . . I know. Such a good . . ."  or fleetingly rare examples from the 19th century or earlier. Oddly one example is from a Scottish writer, which is odd because I am Scottish. LOL

Comment: @BillyKerr What is strange about "have such a good idea" and "know such a good place". This is standard English by any measure.

Comment: @Lambie "I have such a good idea" is fine.   I'm specifically talking about the construction "I know such a good . . .".  This is distinctly odd to me.  I don't know why. And google ngram seems to support my suspicion as this particular usage seems to be fleetingly rare.

Comment: @BillyKerr I know such a good place to have dinner. Shall we go there?  Totally standard English. ngrams cannot check speech so who cares.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to use "so" as an intensifier in a predicate, like "That cake is *so* good" (meaning "very good"). It is less often used with an attributive adjective. It is possible to say "That is a so good cake", it is less common, and should probably be avoided.

There are lots of adverbs that you can use instead of "so": Very or Really for example. You can also try to use a range of words that mean "very good": Fantastic, Excellent, Superb.

Comment: "That is a so good cake" is a no-go. Why even mention it?

Comment: Because whether the sentence "a so good X" is exactly what the questioner asked about "Can you say 'I know a so good place'?".  I'm not sure what you mean by "no-go"  It's possible, but not great. I've certainly heard similar expressions being used, but I don't recommend them.

Comment: I  never recommend non-idiomatic usages.

Answer (score -1):

Your second example is not somewhere a native speaker would use *so* as an intensifying adverb. *Very*, *extremely* and the like would be used there.

The third example is something you will come across, along with "so good of a place". I'm not sure how to parse it formally, but it comes across as informal - and very, very common in some dialects.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have the definite impression *so good **of** a place* is gaining currency, AND is more common in AmE than BrE. I seem to hear it far more often nowadays than I did decades ago, and it's also pretty certain that as an Internet-connected Brit, I hear relatively more American speech than I used to.

Answer (score -2):

Patterns with "so good a/an X" and "such a good X"

Such is used in speaking to emphasize something being said about something:

- That is **such a good cake**. That is **such a good idea**.
- **Another way to express the same thing is**: That cake is **so good**. That idea is **so good**.

Now, if someone is not paying attention to you, you could say:

- But I know **such a good place**. Why don't you believe me when I tell you that?
- That can also be expressed as: I know a **place that is so good**. Why don't you believe me?

The sentence above can be expressed as: I know **so good a place**. Why don't you believe me?

In these examples, so good a place and such a good place  have basically the same meaning.

Please note: "a so good place" is not grammatical in English.

Summary: "such a good X" can be expressed as "so good an X" or "an X that is so good"

Comment: The downvotes here are mistaken. Too bad.

Comment: But can I replace "so" with "really" or 'very" with no differences?
 I tried so tasteful a pie = I tried really tasteful a pie = I tried very tasteful a pie
Or this is only "so" which can have the article after its adjective without any "I tried really tasteful a pie = I tried very tasteful a pie"

Comment: I tried so tasteful a pie =very poor English. I tried ***such as tasty pie***. or: I tried ***a pie that was so tasty***. Tasteful is not about ***food***. All this is in my answer. Those patterns are interchangeable and mean the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Sometimes, you just have to accept what is offered. I think I answered your question and then some. :) In you examples only the first one works.