# Can "how" and "such" be at the begining of sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can you tell me how to use *such* and *how* at the beginning of sentences?
For examples:

> _______ lovely you look in this dress!
>
> a) how
>   b) such

---

> _______ nice weather to go for a walk!
>
> a) how
>   b) such

---

> _______ beautiful your dress is!
>
> a) how
>   b) such

Comment: Are these exercises from a book? Or examples you made up?

Comment: @J.R. from book

Comment: How can you have come to the conclusion that they may not be so used? Such a belief is not well-founded.

Comment: @SiranushA And what did the chapter in the book preceding these questions say about such usages? What did your teacher say in class? What have been your attempts to answer them on your own before asking for help, and why did you find your own attempts unconvincing?

Comment: @JasonBassford: Ha! Like me, you seem to have discovered that even though as native speakers we have no problem deciding whether to use ***how*** or ***such*** in any given construction, It's devilishly difficult to pin down the factors affecting our choice! Which I guess is why so many non-native speakers seem to get it wrong. That's why I really wanted to answer it, having unsuccessfully searched ELL for any earlier questions on this point. But I am defeated on this one.

Comment: ...It's sad that our comments get rapidly deleted as "irrelevant chat", whereas completely irrelevant requests for further details, source links, etc. get preserved! :(

Comment: I think the earlier ELL question [*The So and Such Choice*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197059/the-so-and-such-choice) is ***very*** closely related to this one. And as I write, no-one has been able to provide a satisfactory answer to that one either.

Answer (score 2):

Both words have several meanings but in the contexts you are asking about, they are *adverbs*. They are both used to express *the extent or degree of something*, but the choice of which to use seems to depend on whether the adjective being exaggerated is a quality *possessed by the subject* or not.

> *How lovely* you look in this dress!

In this example, it is the adjective "*lovely*" which is being exaggerated by the word "how". The person being complimented (you) is the subject, but they do not "possess" the quality of loveliness because it is only being applied to *how they look in the dress*.

Consider this example:

> Such a lovely dress you are wearing!

Here the dress is being assigned the quality of loveliness, and the compliment is about the dress, not how it looks on the person (even though they are wearing it). "Such" is the correct choice.

Some more examples:

> - "Such a nice man!" (the man is nice)
> - "How nice of that man to help me!" (the man's action was nice)
> - "Such a lovely day!" (the day is lovely)
> - "How lovely that the sun came out today!" (the day was lovely because of the sun)

Comment: Depending on which source you get it from, Little Red Riding Hood could have said to the wolf ***How** big your eyes are!*, *You have **such** big eyes!*, or (poetically) ***Such** big eyes you have!* In all of them, ***big*** is an adjective applied to ***eyes***, and both ***how*** and ***such*** effectively function as "intensifiers". But I don't see how anything you've said above nails down the difference in how we decide which word to use in any given context (and it's something *many* learners never seem to grasp, presumably because we native speakers can't explain it very well).

Comment: The ungrammatical use of "such" is a central feature of the ["doge meme"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doge_(meme)), e.g. *"such useful!"*, the point being that dogs don't speak good English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Like you said, it depends on the source. This ngram, which compares capitalised "Such big" and "How big" (which would appear at the beginning of a sentence) against their mid-sentence counterparts and while I agree it has been used, it is hardly the norm. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How+big%2Chow+big%2C+Such+big%2C+such+big&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHow%20big%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20big%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSuch%20big%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuch%20big%3B%2Cc0